# Normed spaces and closed sets.

Tags: normed-spaces, complete-spaces

I'm doing a research project for my mathematics class and i need your guys help. I'm almost done but I'm stuck on one proof that i need for the project. The question is as follows:

Let (R^p, ||.||) be a complete normed space. Prove that a closed subset ***A*** of R^p is complete.

If anyone could please assist me with this proof, I would greatly appreciate it.

thanks.

Comment: Use the fact that it contains and all its limit points

Comment: A closed subset of any complete metric space is complete.  The proof is one line.  Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in the subspace $S$.  It converges in the larger space $X$ to some limit $x \in X$ by completeness of $X$.  But $S$ is closed.  Therefore...

Answer (score 0):

The key idea is a closed set contains all of its limit points.